# Give React Prop an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

Hello guys I have some problem, so I like to work with interfaces to not mix up stuff and also to keep readability and have intellisense
Now my Problem, i would like to use this also with given data (through props), but I cant work out how to do so
here is an example I wrote
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-easley-y82ox?file=/src/App.js:0-748

So I would like to get an error before its rendered that the given prop is not the correct type
How would this possible ? I tried writing the type inside the constructor function Test({ q }: Question) and also the given PropType by React -> dont get intellisense and also couldnt figure it out with the interface
I am sure i am missing something or not understanding the real difference, I am not trying to work it out for hours. Would be glad for some help

Answer (score 1):

From your code sandbox, your file is in JavaScript `.js` not TypeScript `.ts` or preferably for React `.tsx` which will give you intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

- as noted in John's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67849570/3388225) you have to rename your files' extensions to `.tsx` for TS to work correctly on them
- right now your `Question` interface is defined as

```ts
interface Question {
    question: String;
    answers: [];
}
```

While the `testCorrect` variable's type should be defined as:

```
interface Question {
    question: string
    answers: string[]
}
```

- the type of `Test` component then should be written as:

```ts
interface TestProps {
  q: Question
}

function Test({ q }: TestProps): JSX.Element {
...
}
```

Or if you prefer to make it inline:

```typescript
function Test({ q }: { q: Question }): JSX.Element {
...
}
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wzylrm)

Comment: Appreciate this, I was looking exactly for that. Thanks. One more question. So I am using a Context.Provider to pass my data (generated stuff) and agan I am missing how to declare the type

Here is my example (now everything should be good, earlier I forgot to change the file, in my applicaation I did have the correct extension, now with your solution it works)
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dew-43m4k?file=/src/test.tsx

Comment: That's kind of tough to answer this in a comment. I've made some adjustments to your code at sandbox. Hope you'll able to follow them. https://codesandbox.io/s/little-frost-zcede?file=/src/test.tsx

Comment: Thank you, yeah I kinda understand it but I feel is a big pain in the ass setting up always the types. Its more extra work then really any help :/